# How to declare a global array in a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to declare a global array in a form?
I need the array to be populated in one procedure, and read in another procedure.
With the current code in line 1 of`FillArray_1`

```vb
array1 = Array( ...
```

I get an error message:

```
Expected variable or procedure, not project
```

Code:

```vb
Dim array1() As String                  ' Array

Private Sub Exe_btn_Click()
    PrintArray
End Sub

Public Sub FillArray_1()
    array1 = Array( _
                               "member_1", _
                               "member_2", _
                               "member_3")
End Sub

Public Sub PrintArray()
    FillArray_1                   

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
                Debug.Print array1(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually there is no benefit on using [Integer vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates,`Array`is the name of your project! Rename project or you have to use`VBA.Array`to avoid this conflict:

```vb
Public Sub FillArray_1()
    array1 = VBA.Array( _
                               "member_1", _
                               "member_2", _
                               "member_3")
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

Not Dim but *Public*:

```
Public array1() As String
```

and it can't be located in the form's module. Move it to a code module.

Comment: Yes. It must be reachable all the time, so move it to a code module.

Answer (score 1):

And to fill `array1` with the `Array()` function, you must declare it as `Variant`.

```
Dim array1 As Variant
```

or

```
Public array1 As Variant
```

if these functions are in different modules.